# Why does sbt give multiple dependencies warning with Akka and ScalaTest dependencies?

Tags: scala, sbt, akka, scalatest

I've just added ScalaTest to `build.sbt` so it now looks as follows:

```
name := "appname"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.4.1",
  "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "2.2.4" % "test"
)
```

After that I am receiving the warning message:

```
SBT project import
         [warn] Multiple dependencies with the same organization/name but different versions. To avoid conflict, pick one version:
         [warn]  * org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:(2.11.2, 2.11.7)
         [warn]  * org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.11:(1.0.2, 1.0.4)
```

I also tried changing the line concerning ScalaTest into:

```
"org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.4" % "test"
```

but the warning still remains the same as above.

How could I deal with this issue since I haven't anywhere written "reflect" or "xml" in my project. I am using the newest version of both Akka and ScalaTest and Scala version 2.11.

Comment: Please always use `%%` for cross-built Scala dependencies (so you don't risk Scala version mismatch when `scalaVersion` and the versions of dependencies don't match).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution might be to add explicitly one of proposed versions by SBT. All warnings pass away when `libraryDependencies` is:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.4.1",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.4" % "test",
  "org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % "2.11.7",
  "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-xml" % "1.0.4"
)
```

Comment: @Jacek Laskowski why haven't you corrected this percent into two in the line with scala-reflect?

Comment: A nice catch! The reason is that the library belongs to a given version of Scala (and it'd have introduced a duplication). That's why there's the sbt idiom for checking `scalaVersion` and react appropriately, i.e. include `scala-reflect` or not - consult [Mixing with managed dependencies](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Configuring-Scala.html#Mixing+with+managed+dependencies).

Answer (score 6):

In your particular case this is related to the ISSUE [1933](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1933)  and you can ignore it for now. You can also explicitly specify version of the dependency you need, to silence warnings.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is fixed with `sbt 0.13.12`